# Pass values from url to another redirected url

Tags: get

zero.php

```
<?php
    $q = $_GET['id']; 
    echo = $q 
?>
```

this code is not working, Help me!

I am not using `.htaccess` in this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
<?php
$q = $_GET['value'];
echo $q;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is significantly off.

Have you tried?

```
<?php
$q = $_GET['id'];
echo $q;
?>
```

and of course this is assuming that there is a GET parameter called id it is being passed so a even better solution would be to check to see if it is defined first.

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $q = $_GET['id'];
    echo $q;
} else {
    echo "ID PARAMETER NOT SET";
}
?>
```